# Plesk NodeJS is showing 404 Page Not Found Error

Tags: node.js, plesk, plesk-onyx

I am running NodeJS on one of my subdomains on plesk panel.
I set the application directory and startup file correctly but when I open the subdomain url on my browser, I get a 404 error which says page not found.
In my logs, I see this error

```
.732 [INFO] [188.158.19.112:8597] Index file is not available in [/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/hello-world/public/]
```

It seems that it is looking for index file instead of running the NodeJS app.js file